# How to know amount of max virtual memory allocated to a process?

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, operating-system

I have a process/Linux, which runs out of memory very soon, and I wonder that it might be because per process max allowable virtual memory set by system setting might be low, in which case the process will soon run out of memory irrespective of how much RAM/virtual memory is available.

What is the command to check max allowable memory to a user process?

Comment: `ulimit -aH` iirc (no shell to test at the moment)

Comment: Address space fragmentation can be a problem too, irrespective of how much memory the process can still allocate.

Comment: @p2pnode:other than ulimit , have you really checked the system memory status using top command ? it might happen that some process leaking the memory. is it a embedded board with no swap space? in that case do you see OOM killer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the command you are looking for is

```
ulimit -m
```

Forgot to add, if you are on a 64 bit machine, it will probably show you unlimited.